# Adding element to XML schema PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have to add a new element to the existing XML schema. My existing XML schema looks like this.

```
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="sample">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="id1" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="id2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="id3" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
```

Now i need the resultant schema , like this..

```
  <xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="sample">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="id1" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="id2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="id3" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="id4" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
```

New Element `id4` to be added under the element sample. I tried `createElement` and `appendChild`, its not working properly. Help me to solve this prob

This is the code which i have tried to add a new element

```
$schema_dom=new DOMDocument($schemaxml); 
$respondent=
$schema_dom->getElementsByTagName('sample');
firstname=$schema_dom->createElement('id4'); 
$respondent->appendChild($firstname);
$schemaobj=$schema_dom->saveXML();
```

Here in the above code, $schemaxml is a string variable contains the XML schema.above code gives me an error saying that `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::appendChild()`.

Comment: Please atleast give it a try before asking for suggestions/help

Comment: @SaurabhSinha: I have mentioed the code part. Any other suggestion??